# Appcelerator Titanium - failed Facebook module login

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-facebook

I've added the facebook module (https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook) to my app and followed the instructions on page.

When I invoke `Alloy.Globals.Facebook.authorize();` I get an error: `Uncaught undefined is not a constant in com.facebook.login.LoginBehavior`

[image]

Same code is working on iOS. What should I be doing to make this work on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not with the `Alloy.Globals.Facebook.authorize();` statement, you need look for statment like `fb.setLoginBehavior(fb.LOGIN_BEHAVIOR_NATIVE);`, Just try and comment the statement and see this would do the trick.

Or else just try and set this `LOGIN_BEHAVIOR_DEVICE_AUTH` property in the method.

In my opinion you can comment and remove the statement, as this method might not work for android.

**Good Luck & Cheers**

Ashish Sebastian